# Scrolling a list on iOS after updating the list fails - need to blur and focus again

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, vertical-scrolling

I have a table with 25 rows. When I change the paging to show 50 rows, I must tap somewhere else on the page, then tap back into the table before it will scroll.

The # of rows doesn't matter, 25>50, 25>100, 50>25, the issue is with replacing the content of the table.

This only seems to affect iOS Safari.

I have tried to blur then focus the

This issue can be reproduced really easily - please test this simple codepen by loading it on iPad in Safari, scroll the list to the bottom, then hit the "Do It Again" button and try to scroll back to the top of the list.

It will only work after tapping into one of the edit windows, then back to the list.

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<button id="doItAgain">Do It Again</button>

//method to build a random string
function makeid(length) {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
  }
  function buildRows(){
    var $rows = [];
    for(var x=0; x<50; x++){
    var $row = $("<tr><td>"+makeid(25)+"</td></tr>");
    $rows.push($row);
  }
  $("#myTable tbody").html($rows);
}

$("#doItAgain").click(buildRows);

buildRows();
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVjbam

The table should be scrollable immediately after updating without any other steps.

Comment: Your demo is working fine in Safari on iOS 12 on an iPhone. After clicking the bottom it is immediately possible to scroll the list to the top. In which iOS version and on which device does this fail?

Comment: Thanks for responding. This is on iPad Air, iOS 12.1. Interesting it works on iPhone but not iPad.

Comment: Thanks, but in my app that does not seem to be the issue - the scrolling table is contained within a flexbox div, so there is no global page scrolling.